# Login to Website via iFrame

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, sharepoint, iframe

I'm currently trying to create an App for SharePoint that renders a login page within the SharePoint Site. This works perfectly fine. However, this login page is expecting the user to login and when I try to do it in Chrome, it works fine. However when I try and do it in Internet Explorer, the screen just flashes and it clears out the user/pass fields. If I try bad credentials, I get the expected result.

I noticed that Visual Studio has a control called `AppIFrame` but when I try and add it to the Solution, nothing happens. In addition, there is literally ZERO documentation on this control, how it works, or what it does. I'm trying to use it under a heavy assumption that it might solve my problem but if anyone can provide me with any sort of information on the AppIFrame control, i'd LOVE it!

Below is the code I'm using which works in Chrome, but not IE:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <iframe src="https://myLoginPage.com" height="800px" width="100%">

    </iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

I've read a bunch of threads about Platform for Privacy Preferences (P3P) but I'm not confident that's what's going on here as most people in those threads have just identified it as bug and has been working since IE 8 (I'm using IE 11).

Thanks in advance for *any* helpful input.